# How much power can a thin wire handle before heating too much?

Tags: temperature, microwave

If I have a copper wire 25um in diameter and 3mm long, and I'm running AC current through it at 3GHz, how can I calculate how much it heats up given a power and duration? The wire is immersed in oil at room temperature, and I don't want to burn the oil, even at the wire's surface. The oil has dimensions about 3mm\$\times\$3mm\$\times\$0.15mm and is in contact with a large chunk of aluminium on one of the flat sides (the wire is suspended about 0.1mm away).

Eg. 16W @28Vrms for 10us (it's a 50ohm system) with 50% maximum duty cycle

Is  this something I can look up, or do I need to plug it into a simulator?

Comment: What kind of oil use as coolant?

Answer (score 2):

Skin depth at 3GHz is only 1.2um, you'll need to consider that. I have no idea if [this](http://chemandy.com/calculators/round-wire-ac-resistance-calculator.htm) calculator is accurate, but it gives a resistance of 18.8 ohms for 100mm of straight 25um wire. However AWG 30 is more like 250um (0.25mm), so which is it?  It would be more like 1.8 ohms for 100mm of 250um wire. Note that at 3GHz and this kind of diameter, the resistance is roughly proportional to the reciprocal of the diameter rather than the reciprocal of the diameter squared, since it's only a thin shell around the outside that's doing all the work.

In the case of 250um, that's about 50x as much resistance as the wire exhibits for low frequencies.

AC resistance will let you calculate the power dissipation, but calculating the temperature rise will not be easy- there may be tables used by transformer designers (since large transformers are often immersed in oil) but I doubt they go down to 250um let alone 25um.

Comment: right thanks, the 30AWG was a mistake...fixed.

Answer (score 2):

16W for 10us is 160 micro-joules; not very much. Given the mass and specific heat capacity of copper, you can put an upper limit on the temperature increase from a single pulse, by neglecting cooling altogether.

Rate of cooling in oil is difficult to calculate and we don't know the pulse repetition rate, so I can't get much further than that.

At this point you've added a 50% duty cycle, which changes (or clarifies) the situation enormously. You can model it as continuous dissipation at 50% power (with an error bounded by that 8k figure) and given the thermodynamics of conductive cooling I don't know what the answer will be.

Does the oil remain static, or can you pump oil past the wire to improve cooling?

Comment: thanks for the answer; I've added a few more details. So looking at the density of copper, the weight of the wire is about 50\$\mu\$g so that the inverse of heat capacity is about 50000K/J. With 160\$\mu\$J, this means about 8K of temp increase for the wire, ignoring all dissipation.

Comment: Also assuming all electrical power is turned into heat, which it is not. Nonetheless, a very useful bound.

Comment: @IanHincks If you consider the coductor as a hollow cylinder because of skin effect, the calculated mass will be a fraction of μg, those ΔT will is about ten times the 8k.

Answer (score 0):

You can find tables that tell you resistance and current-carrying capacity for 30 gauge wire. Based on the resistance and current that you're putting through it (and ohms law and p = I V), you can calculate how much heat you are putting into it.

Will it heat up too much? Well, that depends on the heat coefficient of the oil and likely the amount of oil and where the oil can dissipate the heat.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Eric . Do you know if the resistance will change much with frequency?

Comment: Too right the frequency has an effect! You are thinking of "skin effect". For 30AWG, the maximum frequency that uses all the copper is: 270 KHz. There's a calculator at: http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/skin-depth.htm which says that, by the time you reach 6GHz, your effective depth is 0.85 MICRO metres. Twelve wires in parallel would be equivalent to 39AWG, with current limit of 0.0175 Amps. See: http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

Comment: What is the boiling point of the oil? If you put 16W in for 10usec, how long does the system "rest" to recover, ie. what is the duty cycle? Oil cooled pulse networks in a radar can putout a Megawatt pulse, but the gap between pulses gives an "average" power in the low Kilowatts.